# Using Procedure in Trigger in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Well I have this Procedure:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_salary (job_id employees.job_id%TYPE, salary employees.salary%TYPE)
IS
maxSal NUMBER;
minSal NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT MAX(salary) INTO maxSal FROM employees WHERE job_id = job_id;
SELECT MIN(salary) INTO minSal FROM employees WHERE job_id = job_id;
IF maxSal >= salary OR minSal <= salary THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Invalid slary '||salary||'. Salaries for job '||job_id||' must be between '||minSal||' and '||maxSal);
END IF;
END;
```

This `PROCEDURE` has two parameters. It checks if the `salary` of a `job_id` is between the `max` and the `min` of the job.

Now I want to create a `TRIGGER`.

If `INSERT` or `UPDATE` is called on employees I want to execute the prodcedure. But I don't know what I should write as a parameter in the procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_salary_trg 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
check_salary(); --Don't know which parameter I should use
END;
```

Comment: Pass `:new.job_id` and `:new.salary` but I am not sure if you will get table mutating error or not

Answer (score 2):

You should use :NEW as New Row and :OLD as Old Row.
But I think it is not useful to create a trigger as BEFORE INSERT.
You may create a trigger as AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE.
Here is an example :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_salary_trg
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEE
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
   check_salary(:NEW.job_id);

   EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
       RAISE;
END check_salary_trg;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the job_id and the salary

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_salary_trg 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON employees
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    BEGIN
    check_salary(:new.job_id, :new.salary);
    END;
```

Comment: The syntax is correct, however you will get an `ORA-04091: table HR.employees is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` error

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit And how do I avoid that error?

Comment: You would need a [Compound Trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS2005) or preferably encabsulate all in a stored PL/SQL procedure.